# Is there a "Weierstrass form" for isogenies?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, cubics, abelian-varieties

Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ denote smooth subsets of $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by Weierstrass equations and suppose $\varphi : W_1 \rightarrow W_2$ is an isogeny. Is there a specific form that $\varphi$ can be assumed to take, a sort of "Weierstrass form" for isogenies?

Comment: When you say "smooth subsets of $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by Weierstrass equations" you mean "elliptic curves", right? There's alway's Velu's formulae...

Comment: On the complex torus side (so $(\wp(z),\wp'(z)) = (x,y), y^2 = x^3-ax-b$) it is not hard to obtain $\wp(z) \mapsto P(z)= \wp(z)+\sum_{c \in \ker(\varphi), c \ne 0} \frac{\wp'(c)^2}{(\wp(z)-\wp(c))^2}-\frac{(?)}{\wp(z)-\wp(c)}$, $\wp'(z) \mapsto P'(z)$ for an isogeny $\varphi : E \to E/\ker(\varphi)$ which is [Velu's formula](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5abe/24623f165f8b27b734e2d272025c802223e7.pdf). (?) is the constant you need for the residue at the double poles being $0$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, for me, an elliptic curve is a smooth projective curve of genus $1$ (that's irreducible and algebraic) together with a distinguished point. Famously, all such curves are isomorphic to smooth subsets of $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by Weierstrass equations with the distinguished point taken as $[0:1:0]$, so the study of elliptic curves can, in some sense at least, be reduced to the study of smooth Weierstrass curves, which is what I think you're calling an elliptic curve.